# Проблемы работы с драйверами npreal2 от MOXA

Tags: com, com-порт

Работаю на Ubuntu Server 22.04 с драйверами COM-портов npreal2 от MOXA. Суть проблемы в том, что после после каждого обновления ядра Linux драйвера работают некорректно, нельзя обратиться к портам командами `stty` и `cat` (например `stty -F /dev/tty01` или `cat /dev/tty01`), выводится, что нет таких файлов или каталогов.

Проблему можно, конечно, решить путём запуска скрипта mxinstl из папки moxa и в принципе всё будет работать правильно. Но загвоздка в том, что через порты у меня уже идёт постоянный опрос устройств (это и сплит-системы, и кондиционеры, и датчики температуры и т.д.), а когда после обновления ядра опрос прекращается на довольно долгое время, так ещё после выполнения скрипта mxinstl слетают конфигурации для всех портов и приходится каждый  заново настраивать вручную, то ситуация становится довольно критичной.

В связи я этим вопрос, можно ли как-то настроить всё так, чтобы после обновления ядра не приходилось всё каждый раз настраивать вручную?